# Self sizing cell UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout won't work with image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm trying to make this screen [image: this screen.]

I use UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout with self-sizing cell, but because of the size of the image it doesn't work. I tried changing the priority of the constraints, but it didn't lead to anything. Tell me how to achieve the desired result?

### Failure

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
("<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000009bde00 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fcf14f14240.height == 0   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000098c9b0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fcf14d0bab0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcf14f14240 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000098cc30 UIImageView:0x7fcf14d0bab0.height == 225   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000098ce60 V:[UIImageView:0x7fcf14d0bab0]-(15)-[UILabel:0x7fcf14f12220]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000098cf50 UILabel:0x7fcf14f12220.bottom == UIView:0x7fcf14f14240.bottom   (active)>")
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000098cc30 UIImageView:0x7fcf14d0bab0.height == 225   (active)>
```

### Create Section

```
private func createMainSection() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .estimated(225))

    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)

    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: size, subitem: item, count: 1)

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = .init(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20)

    return section
}
```

### Cell Layout

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.addSubview(posterView)
    contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(overviewLabel)

    posterView.anchor(
        top: contentView.topAnchor,
        right: nil,
        bottom: nil,
        left: contentView.leftAnchor,
        width: 150,
        height: 225)

    titleLabel.anchor(
        top: contentView.topAnchor,
        right: contentView.rightAnchor,
        bottom: nil,
        left: posterView.rightAnchor,
        paddingLeft: 15)

    overviewLabel.anchor(
        top: posterView.bottomAnchor,
        right: contentView.rightAnchor,
        bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor,
        left: contentView.leftAnchor,
        paddingTop: 15)
}
```

### Anchor Func

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

if let top = top {
    topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop + topInset).isActive = true
}
if let right = right {
    rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
}
if let bottom = bottom {
    bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom - bottomInset).isActive = true
}
if let left = left {
    leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
}
if width != 0 {
    widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
}
if height != 0 {
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
}
```